# react native mapbox does not load map in release APK

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

**Describe the bug**

In my case Map is not displaying in release APK(Marker is showing properly). However debug build is ok.

I also have tested creating different token.

**Example**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Mapbox, {MapView, Camera} from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import {Dimensions, Alert, View, Image, Platform} from 'react-native';
const appConfig = require('../../../app.json');
Mapbox.setAccessToken(appConfig.mapboxAccessToken);

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      basicSetup: {
        showUserLocation: true,
        centerCoordinate: [],
        zoomLevel: 12,
        maxZoomLevel: 19,
        compassEnabled: true,
        logoEnabled: false,
        attributionEnabled: false,
      },
      disable: {
        zoomEnabled: false,
        scrollEnabled: false,
        pitchEnabled: false,
        rotateEnabled: false,
      },
    };
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={[styles.map, style]}>
        <MapView
          styleURL={appConfig['someconfigname']}
          style={{flex: 1}}
          ref={(ref) => {
            this.control = ref;
          }}>
          <Camera ref={(c) => (this.camera = c)} zoomLevel={14} />
          {children}
        </MapView>

        {hideLogo ? null : (
          <View style={[styles.logo, logoStyle]}>
            <Image
              resizeMode={'contain'}
              source={require('../../../resources/images/map_logo.png')}
              style={{flex: 1}}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;

const styles = {
  map: {
    width,
    height,
  },
  logo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 20 : 40,
    left: 20,
    shadowColor: '#37474f',
    shadowOpacity: 0.24,
    shadowOffset: {height: 2, width: 0},
    elevation: 3,
    shadowRadius: 3,
  },
  circle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#111',
    backgroundColor: '#03111111',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  circleCenter: {
    height: 4,
    width: 4,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#a1a5d1',
  },
  radiusText: {
    fontSize: 13.47,
    color: '#a1a5d1',
  },
};
```

**Expected behavior**

It should display map even though it is in release mode

**Screenshots**

======= Debug mode =======
[image]

======= Release Mode =======
[image]

**Platform**: [Android]

**Device**: [One Plus 7T]

**Emulator**/ Simulator: [no]

**OS**: [Android 9]

**react-native-mapbox-gl Version** [8.1.0-rc.1]

**React Native Version** [0.62.2]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved now. Android was blocking custom style url, thats why the map was not loading. Just had to add some network rule to bypass that. In android manifest file under application tag added this ,

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

And , in that xml file added the network rule that we need to implement,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">custom style url</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```